# HP better on lower CP Pokemon with same IVs than higher CP?

Tags: pokemon-go

Why is the HP better on the lower CP Jumpluff with worse IVs but same HP as a better IV and higher CP one?

Surely the higher CP one should have more HP than the lower CP one and the HP IV is the same for each? The higher CP one I powered up.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Simply because the left Jumpluff has an higher level than the right one.

I aligned the two images, and you can see that the left one has the white bar a little more filled.

[image]

If you power up the right one both should end with 149HP.